# Is a domain joined windows machine's objectGUID or ObjectSID as stored by Active Directory also stored locally?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, uuid, guid

I need to link a computer to an object in Active Directory.

Basically, I need to link a locally available property to a property that can be found in AD so I can positively link the device to the computer object in Active Directory. The device may be off network, and not able to access a domain controller when it is queried.

From research, the computer's objectGUID or objectSID attributes stored locally do not match the AD ones.

ie:

```
get-adcomputer -identity ComputerName -property MachineGUID,SID
```

returns different GUID and SID than the ones found via

```
wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid
```

and PSTools's

```
PSGetSID
```

..so, is there an indentifier that can be retrieved both locally and in AD that can allow to match a computer?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I deserve a downvote, but sure motivating it would be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Try locally:

```
Get-WmiObject -class SoftwareLicensingService | Select-object ClientMachineID
```

and then on AD Domain controller:

```
Import-module activedirectory
$ComputerName="enter computername here"
$Computer = Get-ADComputer –Identity $ComputerName –property *
$ComputerCMID = Get-WmiObject –computer $ComputerName -class SoftwareLicensingService | Select-object ClientMachineID
Write-Output "$ComputerName has the CMID: $ComputerCMID "
```

Comment: sorry, but you're reading WMI twice, not getting data from AD and locally